# How to submit a Windows desktop app for review by Facebook

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am writing a windows desktop app in VS2010 C# and I want to add functionality to upload photos to Facebook.  To do this I must submit my app for review on the Facebook Developers site.

Before I can submit my app I must Add a Platform in the App Settings tab. When I try this, the platforms available for selection are Facebook Canvas, Website, iOS, Android, Windows App, Page Tab, Xbox and PlayStation.

Unfortunately, none of these platforms are right for my app.  The 'Windows App' platform is the closest match but this is only for Windows 8 Store apps, not Windows desktop apps.

So can anyone tell me how I submit a Windows desktop app for review?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook support.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Facebook documentation, you should add an website as a platform and give detailed screenshot of the integration.

Check this-
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review